# Laravel query scope leads to wrong pagination count

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I wrote this Trait to use Full Text Search with Eloquent Models

```php
<?php
 
namespace HepplerDotNet\FullTextSearch;
 
trait FullTextSearch
{
    /**
     * Replaces reserved characters with full text search wildcards
     *
     * @param string $term
     * @return string
     */
    protected function fullTextWildcards($term)
    {
        // removing symbols used by MySQL
        $reservedSymbols = ['-', '+', '<', '>', '@', '(', ')', '~','*','%'];
        $term = str_replace($reservedSymbols, '', $term);
 
        $words = explode(' ', $term);
 
        foreach($words as $key => $word) {
            /*
             * applying + operator (required word) only big words
             * because smaller ones are not indexed by mysql
             */
            if(strlen($word) >= 3) {
                $words[$key] = '+' . $word . '*';
            }
        }
 
        $searchTerm = implode( ' ', $words);
 
        return $searchTerm;
    }
 
    /**
     * Scope a query that matches a full text search of term.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query
     * @param string $term
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function scopeSearch($query, $term)
    {
        $columns = implode(',',$this->searchable);
 
        $query->whereRaw("MATCH ({$columns}) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE)" , $this->fullTextWildcards($term));
 
        return $query;
    }
}
```

If I run `Model::search('foo')->paginate(10)` it works fine.

But if I run `Model::search('foo')->orWhere('name','like','%foo%')->paginate(10)` it returns the same result, but Paginator shows the count of **all** entries in database instead of the actual result count.
This leads to dead pagination links.